# "FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'C:\Users\flutter\bin\cache\lockfile' (OS Error: Access is denied

Tags: flutter

```
 "FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'C:\Users\flutter\bin\cache\lockfile' (OS Error: Access is denied.
```

This message occurred while flutter doctor command.

Comment: Please some one help what i can do?

Comment: Did you copy project from macOS or clone from git?

Comment: Andrey Molochoko i was re-installing Flutter SDK then it showing me this kind of error.

Comment: Location of your previous fluuter sdk is equals current version?

Comment: Andrey im uninstalled the old sdk and re-installing new sdk ver. The old flutter sdk ver-1.07 and the new sdk ver-1.12.After that when i am doing command "flutter doctor" it is give me this kind of error.Im trying this installation almost 4 times but same error appears and the location is C>>Usres>>flutter.